# dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier in SearchDisplayController return Cell with nil fields for Custom Cell in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I create a page with TableView and SearchDisplayController. **I registered the class** with SearchDisplayController as 
`self.searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView.registerClass(MyCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "someIdentifier");`

When i try to **deque cell** for my SearchDisplayController it return me a cell but **its fields are nil**. i did this
`var myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("someIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as MyCell;`
**This statement is executed successfully** but when i want to **set some value on my custom Cell** e.g `myCell.myTitle.text = "Something";`
it throw exception `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

When i debugged the code i found that all fields in `MyCell` including `myTitle` are `nil`

I don't know what is wrong with it. i have done everything. My Exact code in Objective C was working fine but in swift it is giving my such strange exceptions.

Comment: Please show the `init` methods of MyCell.

Comment: There is nothing in init method. `- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}` i overrided just this method

Comment: `MyCell` class is `Objective C` class and i am using it in `Swift View Controller`. Early i was using it with `Objective C View Controller` and it was working fine.

Comment: If there is no code in init, your labels won't be created. I guess when you used the cell from Objective-C you actually used a cell prototype from a storyboard. If you register your cell in code this prototype cell won't be used.

Comment: Nope i used on objective C the same way i am using here. I registered MyCell with SearchDisplayController and used it and all was good. but it is not working in swift only :/

Comment: So "working fine" just means it does not crash? In Objective-C it won't crash if these are nil, but it shouldn't show anything if the labels don't exist. If you are okay that nothing is visible just use `myCell.myTitle?.text = "Something"`.

Comment: no working fine mean everything is visible properly. I want them to show the value that i set.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch what should i put in `init` to make it work?

Comment: Did you ever get this solved? I'm facing the same problem.